# high latency on LAN

Tags: osx-lion, lan, latency

I have setup a LAN using mac airports and the nodes are macminis.
The OS is Lion 10.7.3.
the macport connect to the Internet using cable and the internal connection is wireless.
I tried to ping each machine. The latency is very high, from several ms to 1s.
But the latency is just below 1ms if I use cable instead of wireless.
Does anybody know why this problem happen?

Comment: sorry, I'll ask my question there.